# How can I trade using IP address and AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, trading

I have been running trading bots on my local desktop and recently thought it's slowly dying. I am trying to run the same python script on AWS, preferably something cheap like Lambda. But I need local IP address to use this 3rd party trading API to buy/sell, and I am wondering if that would work even when hosted on AWS.

I am new to AWS btw.

Comment: None of this makes sense, why would you need a _local ip_? Scripts generally don't need to be on your home computer for it to work, so if you're just looking for someone to say 'this will probably work', then yes... try it. But it's probably much easier to start with an ec2 instance as this sounds like the type of things that's continously running and not event-based, which is what lambda is better at.

Comment: I edited the question. I need to register the local IP to use a 3rd party api. And thanks for outlining the AWS applications.

Comment: I think I know what you mean. If you use an ec2 instance you can assign a *public ip* that doesn't change. I don't think you would have a stable ip when doing requests from a lambda script.

Answer (score 1):

To **associate a static IP address** to an AWS Lambda function:

- Configure the AWS Lambda function to use **private subnets** in a VPC
- Create an **Elastic IP address** (which is a static public IP address)
- Launch a **NAT Gateway** (warning: charges apply!) in the Public Subnet and configure it to use the Elastic IP address
- Provide the Elastic IP address to your third-party for **whitelisting**

All traffic from the Lambda function to the Internet will go through the NAT Gateway and will 'appear' to be coming from the Elastic IP address. It can therefore be used in a **whitelist**.

Alternatively, **you could run the scripts on an Amazon EC2 instance** and associate an Elastic IP address to the EC2 instance. The approach to take will depend on whether you are comfortable with Lambda and whether you want to pay for a continuously-running EC2 instance or just pay for Lambda when it is running.